# Proof of continuity of product using little o

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

How correct and how rigorous is this proof using little o notation?  I trying to prove that the product of two continuous functions is continuous without appealing to $\epsilon$-$\delta$.

Let $f,g: D \subseteq \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be continuous functions on $D$.  Then for all $\vec a\in D$ there is a neighborhood $N(\vec a)$ such that for all $\vec x\in N(\vec a)$,

$$f(\vec x) = f(\vec a) + o(1) \\ g(\vec x) = g(\vec a) + o(1).$$

Then

$$\begin{align}(fg)(\vec x) &= f(\vec x)g(\vec x) \\ &= [f(\vec a)+o(1)][g(\vec a) + o(1)] \\ &= f(\vec a)g(\vec a) + [f(\vec a)+g(\vec a) + o(1)]o(1) \\ &= (fg)(\vec a) + o(1)\end{align}$$

Therefore $fg$ is continuous on $D$.$\square$

Comment: This is correct and rigorous but you need the justification for $f(\vec a)g(\vec a) + [f(\vec a)+g(\vec a) + o(1)]o(1) = (fg)(\vec a) + o(1)$ because this is not obvious unless proven via $\epsilon,\delta$ or via laws of limits (which are themselves proved via $\epsilon, \delta$).

Comment: OK cool.  I'll do a little lemma at the beginning that proves $Ao(1) = o(1)$ for constant $A$ and $o(1)o(1) = o(1)$.  Thanks.